# django pagination duplicate posts

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

Hello i got a wierd error pagnation works fine on my home.html but in my categories.html it duplicate post as soon as it paginates how can i fix this.
Here is code to the files that the problem is in.

problem should be from the def CategoryView.

i tried to change the order_by id and some small stuff in the categories but cant understand why post duplicates on pagnation.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView)
from .models import Post, Category, Comment
from .forms import PostForm, EditForm, CommentForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.paginator import Paginator


def LikeView(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk)
    liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('article-detail', args=[str(pk)]))


class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
    cats = Category.objects.all()
    ordering = ['-post_date']
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        return context


def CategoryListView(request):
    cat_menu_list = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'category_list.html', {
                  'cat_menu_list': cat_menu_list})


def CategoryView(request, cats):
    cat_menu_list = Post.objects.filter(
        category=cats.replace(
            '-', ' ')).order_by('-id')
    paginator = Paginator(cat_menu_list, 3)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    return render(request, 'categories.html', {'cats': cats.replace('-', ' ').title(), 'cat_menu_list': cat_menu_list, 'page_obj': page_obj})


class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'article_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(
            ArticleDetailView,
            self).get_context_data(
            *
            args,
            **kwargs)

        stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        total_likes = stuff.total_likes()

        liked = False
        if stuff.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        context["total_likes"] = total_likes
        context["liked"] = liked
        return context


class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add_post.html'


class AddCommentView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'add_comment.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)

    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')


class UpdatePostView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = EditForm
    template_name = 'update_post.html'


class DeletePostView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'delete_post.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

categories.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}


    <h1 class="headerh1">{{ cats }}</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
            <div class="col-md-8 mt-3 left">
                {% for post in cat_menu_list %}
                <div class="card mb-4">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'article-detail' post.pk %}" class="text-dark">{{post.title }}</a></h2>
                        <p class="card-text text-dark h6">{{ post.author.first_name }} {{post.author.last_name }} | {{ post.post_date }}
                            <a href="{% url 'category' post.category|slugify %}">{{ post.category }}</a></p>
                            {% if post.header_image %}
                    <img id="uploadimg" src="{{ post.header_image.url }}">
                {% endif %}
                        <div class="card-text">{{ post.body|safe|slice:":200" }}</div>
                        <a href="{% url 'article-detail' post.pk %}" class="btn btn-info">Read More</a>
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        {% if user.id == post.author.id %}
                        <a href="{% url 'update_post' post.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                        <a href="{% url 'delete_post' post.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                        {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


        <div class="pagination">
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
            <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" class="page-link">&laquo; PREV </a></li>
                {% endif %}
                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="page-link"> NEXT &raquo;</a></li>

                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your models.py but may be the problem is that `category` is a ManyToMany field of `Post`. So you can get the same post twice when you are filtering.

Try to use `distinct()` on your queryset:

```
cat_menu_list = Post.objects.filter(
    category=cats.replace(
        '-', ' ')).order_by('-id').distinct()
```